# Can you specify decision tree splits to manually "replicate" trees?

Tags: decision-tree, rpart

I have three datasets with overlapping predictor and outcome variables. I would like to take the tree (e.g., same predictor variables and splits) I created in dataset 1 with rpart and apply it to datasets 2 and 3. Is this possible to do?